# Value cannot be null, Parameter name: key when saving XML to CSV file

Tags: xml, export, linq-to-xml

I am trying to import xml data and export to csv file. I receive an error that the XElement key is null:

```
        string FILEMNAME = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"configuration\" + SelectedConfig.Text + ".xml");
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILEMNAME);

            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = root.Descendants(ns + "Table1")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element(ns + "Column3"), y => (string)y.Element(ns + "Column2"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("myfile.ini"))
                foreach (var entry in dict)
                    file.WriteLine("set {0} = {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }
```

Comment: Here is the xml file being read. The xml file was created using WriteXML                                                                                           <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <Column1>ProjectName</Column1>
    <Column2>P Name</Column2>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <Column1>ProjectCode</Column1>
    <Column2>P code</Column2>
  </Table1>
  </Table1>
</NewDataSet>

Answer (score 0):

When you explicitly cast to `string` on `x.Element`, if the element is not found it returns `null` (rather than a null reference exception).

One way to get around this is to use the null coalescing operator (`??`) to assign a non-null value:

```
(string)x.Element(ns + "Column3") ?? ""
```

So your LINQ statement would look like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = root.Descendants(ns + "Table1")
            .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element(ns + "Column3") ?? "", y => (string)y.Element(ns + "Column2") ?? "")
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
```

You may want to assign a value other than "" for the null coalescing operator - this is just a simple example.